# UITableView internal inconsistency: _visibleRows and _visibleCells must be of same length

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm currently trying to make a self sizing tableview (where the cells autosize to fit their inner view's autolayout).

One of the cells has a tableview in it. The idea is that the cell should be the size of the contentSize.height of the tableview.

I subclassed UITableView to accomplish this, and when the tableview loads, it looks great. However, this error gets spit out:

`[Assert] UITableView internal inconsistency: _visibleRows and _visibleCells must be of same length. _visibleRows: {0, 4}; _visibleCells.count: 8, _visibleCells:`

Additionally, when I try to scroll the tableview after this error there is very strange behavior and the tableview starts an infinite loop of layoutsubviews.

Any idea what this error means? I haven't been able to find anything substantial referencing this error on the internet. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem with iOS11 but I have normal cells.  I don't know how to go about debugging. Have you had any success yet? `[Assert] UITableView internal inconsistency: _visibleRows and _visibleCells must be of same length. _visibleRows: {0, 13}; _visibleCells.count: 16, _visibleCells:`

Comment: is there a way to avoid putting the table view inside a cell.. can't you just make the cells inside that inner cell as prt of the parent tableview?

Comment: Could you show your TableView delegates code

Comment: You didn't post _any_ of your code so all people can do here is guessing. That's why you get the downvotes. If you want to give others an opportunity to find out what you're doing wrong, please post your subclassed table view's source code as well as the implementation of your two table view's data sources.

Comment: Please provide some code, so people can help you.

Comment: @Micheal I am facing the same issue while moving cell. Did you manage to resolve it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in my case it was due to editing tableview on background queue
use your updating method like this
`DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
      self?.updateUI()
 }`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and noticed that I was forcing reload the tableView during cell creation via a protocol fired by the cell.

**The Problem:**

```
    // ViewController: CellDelegate
        func onFirstUpdate(state: Bool){
          self.moreInfoHidden = state
          self.tableView.beginUpdates()
          self.tableView.endUpdates()
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

                let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
                cell.refresh(self.data)
                cell.delegate = self
                return cell
...

    // MyTableViewCell
    self.firstUpdate = true
    func refresh(_ data: MyItem){
       if firstUpdate{
          self.delegate.onFirstUpdate(true)
          self.firstUpdate = false
       }
    }
```

**The Solution:**

```
1. Removing tableview update as i understood it is not necessary in my case
           func onFirstUpdate(state: Bool){
              self.moreInfoHidden = state
              //self.tableView.beginUpdates()
              //self.tableView.endUpdates()
            }

2. (Not recommended because of degrading performance) Reload whole table properly again. 

       func onFirstUpdate(state: Bool){
          self.moreInfoHidden = state
          self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a tableview with dynamic cell height. Cells are complete with about 30 layout constraints in there.

In the custom cell's -layoutSubviews, there was a call to tell the container tableView to setNeedsLayout.

Everything worked well until I rotated the device causing this error. I'm not hiding cell or anything like that. I presume this is another  bug.

Removing the [[self tableView] setNeedsLayout] is what fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

If your view hierarchy of UITableView is something like this .

- UITableView

  - UITableViewCells
    --- One cell has UITableView
    Follow this step to resize

1.Use tableview delegate method

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
          tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80.0
        let modal = arrData[indexPath.row]
        if modal.isTableViewCell {
        let calculateTableViewHeight = 
        modal.arrInnerTableViewData.count * inner_cell_height
          return calculateTableViewHeight
        }
       return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```

2.Disable the scroll of Inner tableView